# How can I use matplotlib.pyplot in a docker container?

Tags: python, docker, matplotlib

I have a certain setting of Python in an docker image named `deep`. I used to run python code

```
docker run --rm -it -v "$PWD":/app -w /app deep python some-code.py
```

For information, `-v` and `-w` options are to link a local file in the current path to the container.

However, I can't use `matplotlib.pyplot`. Let's say `test.py` is

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2], [3,4])
plt.show()
```

I got this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 3147, in plot
   ax = gca()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 928, in gca
   return gcf().gca(**kwargs)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 578, in gcf
   return figure()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 527, in figure
**kwargs)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 84, in new_figure_manager
   return new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, figure)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 92, in new_figure_manager_given_figure
   window = Tk.Tk()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1818, in __init__
   self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

With solution search, **I am having only one solution**. I figured out I can do if

```
$ xauth list
xxxx/unix:0 yyyy 5nsk3hd                                # copy this list
$ docker run --rm -it -v "$PWD":/app -w /app \
             --net=host -e DISPLAY \
             -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
             deep bash

inside-container$ xauth add xxxx/unix:0 yyyy 5nsk3hd    # paste the list
inside-container$ python test.py                        # now the plot works!!
```

My question is, instead of all those launching `bash`, setting `xauth`, and running Python **inside** container, **can I do such setting with `docker run` so that I can just run the code outside of the container**?

I tried

```
docker run --rm -it -v "$PWD":/app -w /app \
           --net=host -e DISPLAY \
           -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
           -e "xauth add xxxx/unix:0 yyyy 5nsk3hd" \
           deep python test.py
```

using `--entry` parameter, but it didn't work. Please help.

Comment: You could SSH forward the display

Comment: `-e` is environment variable, by the way. Your command isn't using `--entrypoint`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Interestingly, I found quite nice and thorough solutions in ROS community. http://wiki.ros.org/docker/Tutorials/GUI

For my problem, my final choice is the second way in the tutorial:

```
docker run --rm -it \
   --user=$(id -u) \
   --env="DISPLAY" \
   --workdir=/app \
   --volume="$PWD":/app \
   --volume="/etc/group:/etc/group:ro" \
   --volume="/etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro" \
   --volume="/etc/shadow:/etc/shadow:ro" \
   --volume="/etc/sudoers.d:/etc/sudoers.d:ro" \
   --volume="/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw" \
   deepaul python test.python
```

Comment: I have a question: your solution works if I run this from terminal directly.
If I copy it in a *.sh file and try to run the file containing the exact same instructions it did not work. Do you know why?

Comment: `/tmp/.X11-unix` that doesn't exist on os x. what is your host OS?

Comment: How do it work with Window 10? In window don't have `/tmp/.X11-unix`?

Answer (score 4):

Bellow, I have described how to enable matplotlib plotting from running docker container and windows 10 machine.

Note, I **didn't** have to change matplotlib backend using `matplotlib.use('TkAgg')` as maybe others suggested in other posts.

For test I used simple python program:

```
# test.py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2], [3,4])
plt.show()
```

The first thing is to add the following into the dockerfile, to install tkinter backend which matplotlib uses for graphical representation:

```
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y libx11-dev
RUN apt-get install -y python3-tk
```

The second thing is to install [vcXsrv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/) server onto windows machine, which enables and establishes communication from running container to windows machine. Install and run it - you may follow instructions described on this [page](https://dev.to/darksmile92/run-gui-app-in-linux-docker-container-on-windows-host-4kde).

The last thing to do before building and running the docker image is to set `$DISPLAY` variable in wsl terminal. I did this with:

```
export DISPLAY=IP:0.0
```

, where IP is the network IP of windows machine.

In my case I ran:

```
export DISPLAY=172.16.31.103:0.0
```

After successfully executed steps above the image can be built.

Build it with:

```
docker build -t image_name .
```

Then run the container using command below where for display the before-set variable will be used.

```
docker run -ti --rm -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY image_name
```

If everything was set correctly the matplotlib figure will pop-up.

Comment: Work for me.
I work in PowerShell, so instead of `DISPLAY=172.16.31.103:0.0` I used `set-variable -name DISPLAY -value 172.16.31.103:0.0` (with my IP)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there are two ways you can to this:

1. You can give Jupyter a try. Install Jupyter via Conda or pip, and then run Jupyter-notebook server. By exporting the server port of Jupyter, you can visit the Jupyter-notebook via a browser. You can then create a new python notebook and import the .py file you have, copy the code under your `if __name__ == '__main__'` to the new notebook if necessary. Finally, run the code in Jupyter, the image will show up below the code on the web page. `matplotlib` works smoothly with Jupyter. If you are willing to open a browser to run the code and view the result, this is the best way I can think of.
2. You can use the `matplotlib` headlessly. That means to remove all the code such as `plt.show()`. Use `plt.savefig` to save figures to filesystem instead of showing it in an opened window. Then you can check out these saved images using any image viewer.

I tried mounting X11 to docker images some time ago, like YW P Kwon's answer. It will only work on systems that use X11, and you can do this only on a local machine (I am not sure if X11 forward works). It is also not recommended in docker. While with the Jupyter and Headless solution,  you can run your code on any platform. But you do need to modify your code a little bit.

Comment: I am afraid that even without `plt.show()` it still needs a `$DISPLAY` for whatever internal reasons it might be.

Comment: @chiffa Matplotlib starts up with a defined "backend".  Most of these are interactive backends, and look for `$DISPLAY` as you say.  If you use a non-interactive backend, they can work on headless setups.  For example, I do `import matplotlib; matplotlib.use('PDF'); import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` very often.  You could see if that helps.  Source:  https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend

Answer (score 3):

I tried in my own way and it works fine..
#To run "matplotlib" inside docker, you must install these inside containers:-#


*$`yum install python3 -y` //(must)

$`yum install python3-tkinter -y` //(must)

$`pip3 install matplotlib`   // (must)

$`pip3 install pandas` (if required)

$`pip3 install scikit-learn` ( if required)*


Now, run your container.


*$`docker run --rm -it --env=DISPLAY --workdir=/app -v="$PWD:/app  <image_name>  python3 model.py`*

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `matplotlib` is not meant to be used in `docker`. Use `seaborn` instead.

I notice, when encountering that problem, that `matplotlib` was used to show and save figures. `Seaborn` can save files and it works fine in `docker`. Removing `matplotlib` and using `seaborn` might be the solution.