# vscode dev container python interactive (`tkagg`) plots

Tags: docker, matplotlib, tkinter, visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

#### Expected Behavior (local environment: fresh MacOS 12.4 installation)

With no environment updates except `$ pip3 install matplotlib`, I can successfully run [this simple plot from the Matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/simple_plot.html#simple-plot):

###### Example Code:

```
# testplot.py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Data for plotting
t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t, s)

ax.set(xlabel='time (s)', ylabel='voltage (mV)',
       title='About as simple as it gets, folks')
ax.grid()

fig.savefig("test.png")
plt.show()
```

###### Actual Output (saved to a .png after window opens):

Run `$ python3 testplot.py` in the terminal:

[image]

#### Observed Behavior (vscode python 3.8 dev container)

###### Disclaimer: This post does not address notebook-based plots (which work fine but are not always preferred)

However, when I run this in my dev container, I get the following error:

```
testplot.py:16: UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
  plt.show()
```

#### First Attempted Solution:

Following [this previously posted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61863771/1798351), I specified the backend (`export MPLBACKEND=TKAgg`) before running the interpreter, but the error persists.

#### Second Attempted Solution:

Following the comments, I added the following lines to the script:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('tkagg')
```

In the v3.8 dev container, this addition changes the error to:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testplot.py", line 5, in <module>
    matplotlib.use('tkagg')
  File "/usr/local/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1144, in use
    plt.switch_backend(name)
  File "/usr/local/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 296, in switch_backend
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Cannot load backend 'TkAgg' which requires the 'tk' interactive framework, as 'headless' is currently running
```

Note: adding these two lines broke the local script as well.  The point of the local example was to show that it plots stuff without installing anything except matplotlib.

Comment: did you try `matplotlib.use(...)`?

Comment: thanks @PaulH, I've added that case to the attempted solutions

Comment: Ok -- so what's your interpretation of that error message?

Comment: my first reaction was to run `pip freeze` and check whether `tk` was installed, and confirmed that it was via the following listing: `tk==0.1.0`.  aside from that I just googled "tk vs headless python" and didn't find anything helpful.

Comment: if you're running in a container -- there's no GUI framework (head) to interact with, right?

Comment: yeah that's a good point.  although I don't know much about python gui framework, I did check `echo $DISPLAY && xclock` and got an error even though `DISPLAY` is set properly, I think this may be a bug under https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/6184

Comment: For windows machine see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73375874/6274417