# Docker file contents not showing in local repo

Tags: docker, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, dockerfile, docker-machine

Hi I am building a simple python image using docker.
I am using ubuntu 22.04 and vs code as my editor.
I have created a folder inside my local machine and used vs code to write simple python script and created a docker file using vs code and wrote the instructions inside it.
My docker file is created in the local repo but inside the file there is no contents which I wrote using vs code.

I have to copy the content of Dockerfile from vs code and use `vi` to paste inside the empty Dockerfile in my local repo.

Also the image gets built but does not show in `docker ps` as a running state but as exited one in `docker ps -a`

Python Script -

```
import numpy as np  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
a=np.arange(1,18) 
plt.plot(a)  
plt.show()
```

When running `python3 file1.py` in cmd it displays the chart but when running `sudo docker run graph.py` it does not show the graph.
What may be the issue ?
Kindly explain.

My dockerfile -

```
FROM python
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
CMD python file1.py
```

Comment: How are you building and running the image?  You say without Docker, "it displays the chart"; does it show up in a new window?  Running GUI applications in Docker is tricky and non-portable, and I might not bother with a container here.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your dockerfile to below:

```
FROM python
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip3 install -r requirement.txt   (You need to confirm whats the correct name)
CMD python file1.py
```

This should work. Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: Still not showing anything in the Docker file

Comment: Post seeing your edit. it seems you are not facing issues with Dockerfile but with Docker basics. here is the link which will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28212380/why-docker-container-exits-immediately

PS: There is a difference between the Docker image and Container, docker ps shows running container states.

Comment: I know that when the process completes it automatically exit. In my case it exits after file1.py executes. But why is the output not showing i.e. the graph the script displays a simple linear graph. Lastly how to create a running instance of the image.

Comment: Are you 100% sure it works locally? if yes have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46018102/how-can-i-use-matplotlib-pyplot-in-a-docker-container

Comment: Brother still facing the same issue. When I run python3 file1.py it works in cmd but using sudo docker run graph.py its not showing. Do I need to change anything in the run command . I am not able to understand why is it not working

Comment: Rising, your command is incorrect. graph.py is (could be) your project file and has nothing to do with docker as such. to see what the valid parameters to docker run have a look: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/

Comment: Issue is fixed Rising?

Comment: No Its not resolved I am still not able to get it. If I want my output to display on as a webpage can it be done. My vscode issue is still there If I write in my docker file its not showing anything in the local repo of my docker file.